# Swift Float80 data type not available in Xcode 8 beta

Tags: swift, floating-point, double, xcode8

When I run my app in Xcode 7, the Float80 datatype is available and I can look at the source code by pressing command and clicking on the data type.  In Xcode 8 beta, it only goes up to Float64, and Float80 is not included in that file anymore.  Does Float80 have a different name now? Or am I missing something?

Comment: `Float80` is an architecture dependent type, which is not available for ARM-based platforms. Is your project (or Playground) targeting macOS?

Comment: It's targeting IOS and Watch OS

Comment: Float80 is only supported on OS X because it depends on hardware support that isn't available on arm.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is there anything that would have similar precision that would work on the iPhone?

Comment: There is also float96 and osxgmp project in github that provide BigFloat.I'm not sure float96 availability in arm

Answer (score 1):

Like the comments below my question say, Float80 is apparently only available on OSX, but it will compile on the iPhone simulator because that's run in OSX.  Instead of using the Float80 datatype, I ended up using an NSDecimalNumber.  A 64 bit double value can hold about 16 digits, but an NSDecimalNumber can hold up to 38 digits, which is perfect for what I'm trying to use it for.  In Swift 3 you can use it like this:

```
let number = NSDecimalNumber(value: 25)  //decimal that equals 25
print("number: \(number.decimalValue)")  //read-only
number = number.subtracting(5)           //number == 20
number = number.adding(5)                //number == 25
```

The documentation can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/